# Connecting Differential pressure sensor MPXV7002DP to Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, sensor, analog-to-digital, voltage

MPXV7002DP is analog sensor which measures differential pressure and requires 5V supply voltage and gives an output voltage of 4.5V. However, I want to get the digital output so I will connect the sensor to ADC( MCP 3008) which is thus connected to Pi 4.

My only concern is if I will need a voltage regulator as Raspberry Pi pins are only 3.3V tolerant. Any suggestions?

Link - https://makersportal.com/shop/mpxv7002dp-differential-pressure-sensor

Comment: You run an unnecessary risk by connecting 4.5V output to a GPIO input. It should be limited to 3.3V.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [resistor divider](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/voltage-divider-calculator/) between the MCP3008 Dout pin and the Pi GPIO MISO pin.

Or buy a level shifter chip/module.